# How can I know Conv2D parameters inside tflite model using python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I was able to find out each Conv2D's input/output tensor shape inside tflite model with below code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

SAVED_MODEL_PATH = "TFLITEMODEL_PATH.tflite"
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=SAVED_MODEL_PATH)

ops = interpreter._get_ops_details()
for op_index, op in enumerate(ops):
    if op['op_name'] == "CONV_2D":
        cnt += 1
        for tensor_idx in op['inputs']:
            tensor = interpreter2._get_tensor_details(tensor_idx)
            tensor_shape = tensor['shape']
            print(tensor['name'], "\t", tensor['shape'])
        print("----")
```

And Below is the output.

```
Placeholder      [  1 224 224   3]
conv2d/kernel    [64  7  7  3]
conv2d/Conv2D_bias   [64]
----
block-0/denseblock-0-0/Relu      [ 1 56 56 64]
block-0/denseblock-0-0/conv2d/kernel     [32  3  3 64]
block-0/denseblock-0-0/conv2d/Conv2D_bias    [32]
----
block-0/denseblock-0-1/Relu      [ 1 56 56 96]
block-0/denseblock-0-1/conv2d/kernel     [32  3  3 96]
block-0/denseblock-0-1/conv2d/Conv2D_bias    [32]
----
```

But I wonder how can I know its Conv2D parameters(like padding, stride, dilation, etc) with python code. I want to those information like [netron.app](https://netron.app/). It shows all layers and its info like name, padding, stride, etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to do that. `_get_ops_details` isn't a public API and isn't guaranteed to be stable.

May I know what you're trying to achieve?

Technically it's possible to go into the detail, and parse the TFLite FlatBuffer model by your own. However it's not a official path either.